# Tempo Reset API Parameters for Validation API

Tags: api, validation, jira, tempo

We want to consume below tempo API(POST request) for validating whether time sheet period is closed or not , however we are unable to find document talk about required parameter for this API

any help regarding API documentation or parameter will be useful

https://myserver/jira/rest/tempo-rest/1.0/worklogs/validation/date

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Have you check this urls: https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/dishttps://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO/Tempo+API+Guideplay/JTS/Tempo+REST+APIs   and   https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO/Tempo+API+Guide

Comment: Thanks for the link, however we are unable to find the documentation for the specific API :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try passing the following x-www-form-urlencoded parameters in the body of the api-

ansidate - 2016-04-24

formFieldId - date

user - abc

planning -  false

Hope this helps :)

Comment: glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the API documentation
https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/JTS/Timesheets+REST+API

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.